# How am I sure that my process has a user interface?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

When running a class which can be used interactively or silently by batch, I want to display a hourglass, only if in interactive mode.

I found the function `xGlobal::clientKind()` , read below, but not sure it is sufficient (can't batches also run on Client ?)

```
if (xGlobal::clientKind() == ClientType::Client)
    startLengthyOperation();

// here do the process

if (xGlobal::clientKind() == ClientType::Client)
    endLengthyOperation();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not bother to test client kind when using `startLengthyOperation`, the method does a sufficient test itself.

Testing should be like this:

```
if (clientKind() == ClientType::Client)
    ...
```

Don't use `xGlobal::clientKind`, use without qualification.

The `ClientType` has four values, matching what you see in "Online Users".

Batch *can* be called interactively in Basic/Periodic/Batch, but it should be rarely used.